# Curved text in Powerpoint with vertical letter alignment

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint

In PowerPoint, I can use text effects to achieve text following a curve, but this also rotates each individual letter to be aligned with that curve. What I would like to achieve is text which follows a curve, but whose individual letters remain vertically oriented as in an ordinary line of text. Is there a way to do that easily?

I know I can create a ton of little text boxes with each individual letter and position them manually along a curve, but this is obviously tedious, and I was hoping for a builtin solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the screen record below:

[image]